# Issue using SearchHashtag Instasharper

Tags: c#, instasharp

I have been using this api to get  User followers , following etc and the result returned is with a token that can be used in next hit to carry from that onward however i cannot find anything like that on this api :

> SearchHashtag

I have rank token if that is it it does not work basically i am just getting the 50 result again n again here is my code:

> IResult userSearch = await _instaApi.SearchHashtag("string",null,ranktoken);

What am  i doing wrong here?

Comment: This is probably because the Instagram API uses pagination to limit the amount of search results returned, but as I am not familiar with InstaSharp or the Instagram API I cannot help you further

Comment: The other api (getfollowers,getfollwoign etc)have pagination as well unlike this one it does not have that parameter for some reason